# Sort grouped objects by Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have following array of objects:

```
[{
   id: 1,
   amount: 2000,
   date: "2018-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"
},{
   id: 2,
   amount: 3000,
   date: "2017-07-31T00:00:00.000Z"
},{
   id: 3,
   amount: 6000,
   date: "2018-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"
},{
   id: 4,
   amount: 7000,
   date: "2017-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"
},{
   id: 5,
   amount: 5000,
   date: "2017-03-31T00:00:00.000Z"
},{
   id: 6,
   amount: 3000,
   date: "2018-02-22T00:00:00.000Z"
},{
   id: 7,
   amount: 4500,
   date: "2017-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"
}]
```

I am calling following command to group objects by year and date:

```
_(data)
.groupBy(o => new Date(o.date).getFullYear() + '-' + new Date(o.date).getMonth())
.map(o1 => _(o1).map(o2 => o2.amount).sum())
```

Code above give me array of sums like [xx, yy, aaa, bbb, ...]

Now I need ensure that these values in array will be ordered (sum of 2018-2 will be first, and sum of 2017-1 will be on the end).

Also will be nice when result will be contains array of sorted objects as I describe above, where each object will be contains also period key "year-month" to detect what current value is. Expected output will be something like this:

```
[
  {period: "2018-2", amount:3000}, // sum of 2018-2
  {period: "2018-1", amount: 8000 }, // sum of 2018-1
  {period: "2017-7", amount: 3000} // sum of 2017-7
  {period: "2017-3", amount: 5000} // sum of 2017-3
  {period: "2017-1" amount: 11500} // sum of 2017-1
]
```

Is possible edit this chain to get required result please? Thanks!

Comment: Only lodash? Can you use just vanilla js?

Comment: I will prefer cleaner solution, if exists some elegant way in vanilla js I will be fine with it.

Comment: But I hoped it will be possible with chaining in lodash

Comment: why do you want to chain it with lodash when it is completely possible (and even easier to read) without lodash? @Ele's answer covers it pretty well

Comment: @stack001stack001 if you really want to chain it, you just need to adjust your map function to return the object that you want to and afterwards call .sort() with the callback function for your sorting

Comment: @NicolasGehlert I tried edit it and return from map object like `{amount: xxx, period: "xxx" }` but my tries were unsuccessful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the grouped data and sort it ascending (the only possible way with lodash) and reverse the order.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, amount: 2000, date: "2018-01-31T00:00:00.000Z" }, { id: 2, amount: 3000, date: "2017-07-31T00:00:00.000Z" },{ id: 3, amount: 6000, date: "2018-01-31T00:00:00.000Z" }, { id: 4, amount: 7000, date: "2017-01-31T00:00:00.000Z" }, { id: 5, amount: 5000, date: "2017-03-31T00:00:00.000Z" }, { id: 6, amount: 3000, date: "2018-02-22T00:00:00.000Z" }, { id: 7, amount: 4500, date: "2017-01-31T00:00:00.000Z" }],
    result = _(data)
        .groupBy(o => o.date.slice(0, 7))
        .map((array, sort) => ({ sort, date: sort.split('-').map(Number).join('-'), amount: _.sumBy(array, 'amount') }))
        .sortBy('sort')
        .reverse()
        .map(({ date, amount }) => ({ date, amount }))
        .value();


console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is possible to edit comparing? Because when I use another option to concat date, like year + '-' + month (without zero padding it didnt work for 11 and 2 for example)

Comment: @stack001stack001, yes, you could split, map numbers and join with dash, please see edit.

Comment: still doesnt work, check this please https://jsfiddle.net/aLz38yet/1/ , I use your code with different data. In result is 2018-2 before 2018-11

Comment: with loosing the leading zero in the string, sorting returns wrong order. a solution could be to map again or to use a different sorting function which re

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function `reduce` along with the function `Object.values`

*Just vanilla javascript*

```js
var data = [{   id: 1,   amount: 2000,   date: "2018-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"},{   id: 2,   amount: 3000,   date: "2017-07-31T00:00:00.000Z"},{   id: 3,   amount: 6000,   date: "2018-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"},{   id: 4,   amount: 7000,   date: "2017-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"},{   id: 5,   amount: 5000,   date: "2017-03-31T00:00:00.000Z"},{   id: 6,   amount: 3000,   date: "2018-02-22T00:00:00.000Z"},{   id: 7,   amount: 4500,   date: "2017-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"}];

var result = Object.values(data.reduce((a, c) => {
  var [year, month] = c.date.split('-');
  var key = `${year}-${+month}`;
  (a[key] || (a[key] = {period: key, amount: 0})).amount += c.amount;
  return a;
}, {})).sort((a, b) => b.period.localeCompare(a.period));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

With lodash you could first `groupBy`, then sort entries and then `map` those entries to get objects with `period` and sum of `amount` for each period.

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"amount":2000,"date":"2018-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"},{"id":2,"amount":3000,"date":"2017-07-31T00:00:00.000Z"},{"id":3,"amount":6000,"date":"2018-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"},{"id":4,"amount":7000,"date":"2017-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"},{"id":5,"amount":5000,"date":"2017-03-31T00:00:00.000Z"},{"id":6,"amount":3000,"date":"2018-02-22T00:00:00.000Z"},{"id":7,"amount":4500,"date":"2017-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"}]

const result = _.chain(data)
  .groupBy(({date}) => {
    const d = new Date(date)
    return d.getFullYear() + '-' + (d.getMonth() + 1)
  })
  .entries()
  .sort(([a], [b]) => b.localeCompare(a))
  .map(([period, arr]) =>  ({period, amount: _.sumBy(arr, ({amount}) => amount)}))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for help me!  but Nina's solutions looks more clearer so I prefer her, but also thanks a lot